# How do I read or write a cookie in php using gwan?

Tags: php, cookies, g-wan

How do I read or write a cookie in php using gwan? 
I tried use setcookie, but the only variables that appear are get and post in argv.

Comment: I think this question will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886351/gwan-redirection-after-create-cookie . Let me know

Comment: It does not help, it is only for C and others who have the Gwan API internally.

Answer (score 1):

```
char cookies[] = "Cookie: blah\r\n" // add a cookie in the response

http_header(HEAD_ADD, cookies, sizeof(cookies) - 1, argv);
```